# Trying to repeat Quadratic bezier around a Circle in Geometry nodes using index

Tags: geometry-nodes

I want to repeat the quadratic bezier around these points on a circle as annotated in the blender file.

I have tried modulo with index with transfer attribute but I get red wires.

I am unable to upload a picture. Error with the server.
I have uploaded the blender file.
Blender 3.3.1

[image]

Comment: I am having trouble uploading PNGs and JPEGS any one know why?

Comment: Maybe they weigh over 2 MB?

Comment: No they were half MB

Comment: It looks like image uploading doesn't work currently on BSE.

Answer (score 4):

You need to first spawn multiple beziers, then assign the averaged position as the handles (actually it's not an averaged position, just a sum in your case). Unfortunately, those beziers are cubic; if you really care about quadratic beziers you can ask either how to manually create a polyline to fit a quadratic bezier, or how to position cubic bezier handles so that they are equivalent to a quadratic bezier...

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: How did you get the image up?

Comment: @RobinBetts the same way the blend-exchange image is linked, using an HTML tag

Answer (score 4):

This version constructs the inner circle and the petal quadratics at the same time, which saves a few nodes, fiddling with control-points for each circle-side? It just has to do the trig. once to figure out where the circle-corners are on the max Y side, and then it rotates instances of the petal into place:

[image]

Parameters permit changing number of sides, inner/outer radius:

[image]

[image]

It would be up to you to further embellish the circle, convert all to mesh, etc.